# Enthalpy change in an isothermal experiment at constant pressure

Tags: thermodynamics

I read, in a passage regarding isothermal and adiabatic calorimetry for determining heat of solution, that

> In a truly isothermal experiment at constant pressure, $\Delta H$ of the system in the calorimeter differs from zero only because of changes in numbers of moles of various substances in the system.

I am having difficulty understanding this. Under constant pressure,

$$\Delta H = \Delta U + p \Delta V$$

However, in an isothermal process, $\Delta U = 0$. Thus, wouldn't it be the case in the example in the passage that $\Delta H = p \Delta V$?

According to the passage, $\Delta H$ is not equal to zero only when there is a change in the number of moles. Doesn't this then mean that there has to be a change in number of moles so that there can still be a change in volume, allowing for expansion work to be done? Could anyone please point out what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Why do you think ΔU=0 for isothermal process when generally Q<>0 and W<>0 ? 1 kg of ice at 0 deg C has definitely different U than 1 kg of water at the same temperature.

Comment: That is true, but what threw me off was the statement that the change in enthalpy only differs from zero due to the change in the number of moles. I did not know how to interpret this otherwise.

Comment: It is true for ideal gases.

Comment: This assumes that you have a change of phase or a chemical reaction where U and H depend not only on temperature (in the case of ideal gas mixture, say), but also depend on the amounts of the various chemical species present.

Comment: About ice water chemical potential energy is involve not just heat transfer.

Comment: As suggested by previous comments, for an ideal gas $p \Delta V = RT \Delta n$.

Comment: @ChetMiller could you provide some further reading on this?

Comment: See Smith and van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics